# Ember Object.Create() has properties of the last instance

Tags: ember.js

In Ember, this is what I do:

I declare these objects

```
MyObject = Ember.Object.extend({
   //some serialization logic
});

FormViewContainer = MyObject .extend({
   type: "FormViewContainer",
   label: "",
   options: {
       css: "",
       class: "",
       attr: []
   },
  items:[]
});

FormViewField = MyObject.extend({
   type: "FormViewLibreField",
   isCodif: false,
   question: {},
   answer: undefined,
   options: {
      css: "",
      class: "",
      attr: []
   }
});
```

Then in My app:

```
var cont = FormViewContainer.create({
            label: "My Label",
            options: {
                class: "cssclassestuff"
            }
        });

Data.Questions.forEach(function (c) {
            var field = FormViewField.create();
            field.set("question",c);
            cont.get('items').push(field);
        });

//items are in the array, they are 6!
cont.get('items').length == 6
```

Thats the part I dont get. I create a new instance (supposedly), but i

```
FormViewContainer.create().get('items').length == 6
```

Object.Create() actually copied items from the other instance into this new one via my object constructor!

It only copied the "items" property, label and options are not affected.

I tried assigning properties with/without the get/set accessors and got the same result.

If anyone has an Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember has this weird issue(?)/implementation.  Anything that is defined as an array is shared among the instances.

```
 FormViewContainer = MyObject .extend({
    type: "FormViewContainer",
    label: "",
    options: {
        css: "",
        class: "",
        attr: []
    },
   items:[]
 });
```

**Do this**

```
 FormViewContainer = MyObject .extend({
    init: function(){
      this._super();
      this.items = [];
    },
    type: "FormViewContainer",
    label: "",
    options: {
        css: "",
        class: "",
        attr: []
    },
   items:null
 });
```

Comment: I sorted this in the mean time as well by creating the property in the create object. thanks!

Comment: It makes sense that this happens because the array instance in the first example is put on the prototype, so it is available to all instances of the class.

Comment: ahaurw01, that makes perfect sense now that I think about it.  I came from a C family world, so the prototype is a little hard to get use to.  Although I'm not positive why any other string/object etc on the prototype isn't a "shared" string/object.